# How could I modify sharepoint 2013 list column title?

Tags: sharepoint-2013

I want the same column display different title in different views with only one list.
So I append a jquery script in my view.aspx.

```
<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderId="PlaceHolderMain" runat="server">
<script type="text/javascript" src="/_layouts/15/Library/js/jquery-1.9.1.js">      </script>
​<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('[id^=diidSort][id$=company]').text('com');
  });
</script>
```

It works,but when I click column ascending or descending then refresh page. the column
title restore to original text. How could I fix it?

Comment: may be problem with Minimal Download Strategy. Please read article below. And for this purpose I advise to use JSLink. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sridhara/archive/2013/02/08/register-csr-override-on-mds-enabled-sharepoint-2013-site.aspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since it is a SharePoint 2013 environment, the following approach is suggested:

- Create rendering template in order to render the custom column title
  in a List View
- Update List View web part in View page

### Template file

SharePoint 2013 introduces [client side rendering framework (CSR)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj220045.aspx) for List View that allows to define the rendering logic of SharePoint list views using HTML/JavaScript.

The following example demonstrates how to render the custom  title for `Title` column in List View:

```
(function () {


    function preTaskFormRenderer(renderCtx) {
       modifyHeaderData(renderCtx);       
    }


    function modifyHeaderData(renderCtx)
    {
      var viewTitle = renderCtx.viewTitle;
      var linkTitleField = renderCtx.ListSchema.Field[1];
      linkTitleField.DisplayName = viewTitle + ':' + linkTitleField.DisplayName;
    }

    function registerRenderer()
    {
      var ctxForm = {};
      ctxForm.Templates = {};
      ctxForm.OnPreRender = preTaskFormRenderer;
      SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides(ctxForm);
    } 
    ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(registerRenderer, 'clienttemplates.js');

})();
```

### How to apply changes

- Upload the specified script (lets name it `TaskForm.js`) into
  SharePoint `Site Assets` library
- Open View page in edit mode and go to List View web part properties
- Specify `JS Link` property located under `Miscellaneous` group:
  `~sitecollection/SiteAssets/TaskForm.js` (see pic. 1)
- Save changes and repeat steps 2-4 for every View page if needed

[image]

Fig 1. JS Link property

### Result

[image]