# Is there a way to edit a SharePoint List Title?

Tags: json, sharepoint, sharepoint-list

I've been lookin for ways to Format a SharePoint List through json and been able to find a lot of documentation about the columns and rows. The question here is if I'm able to format the title above the list as informed on this image, like making it bigger, changing it's colour, etc.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/16EJ1.jpg

Thank you!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How could I modify sharepoint 2013 list column title?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23645580/how-could-i-modify-sharepoint-2013-list-column-title)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use JSON to format the column or view in the modern list. Unfortunately, there is not JSON formatting to format the list title currently.

As a workaround, we can use SPFx Applications Customiser to inject CSS and JavaScript to achieve it. The following articles for your reference.

[Use an SPFx Application Customizer to add JavaScript (e.g. header) to every page in a site](https://www.sharepointnutsandbolts.com/2017/06/SPFx-Application-Customizer-Global-JS-Page-Header.html)

[SPFx Applications Customiser CSS Injection](https://github.com/hugoabernier/react-application-injectcss)